# navbar toggle animation not working

Tags: css, toggle, navbar

Hi I have this code that animates the toggle when clicked and unclicked. I have copied the code exactly as it says but no animation What am i doing wrong? I have added the css etc.

Its loaded as an external php file but the code is :

```
    <nav class = 'navbar navbar-default'>
<div class = 'navbar-header'>
<button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#example-navbar-collapse' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='navbar'>
  <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
  <span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
  <span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span>
</button><a class = 'navbar-brand' href = '#'>SITENAME</a></div>
<div class = 'collapse navbar-collapse' id = 'example-navbar-collapse'>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>About</a></li>
    </ul>  
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Get bids</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Register company</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Help</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>`
```

and the css is :-

```
    .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;

  &:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
  }

  .icon-bar {
    width: 22px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .top-bar {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 10%;
  }
  .middle-bar {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 90%;
  }
}

.navbar-toggle.collapsed {
  .top-bar {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  .middle-bar {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
```

Sure its simple and im just missing something silly! thankx

Answer (score 0):

You're missing Javascript. The toggling of the `.collapsed` class cannot happen with HTML + CSS alone.

Comment: The sample came with no javascript? The code is on here julienmelissas.com/animated-x-icon-for-the-bootstrap-navbar-toggle/

Comment: https://julienmelissas.com/animated-x-icon-for-the-bootstrap-navbar-toggle/

Comment: View the codepen example: http://codepen.io/JulienMelissas/pen/LEBGLj and then click on the gear icon next to JS and CSS. You'll see jQuery + Bootstrap.js + Bootstrap.css are included. This is a bootstrap utilizing demo.

Comment: Hi, I can see everything but i dont seem to be missing any of it? I have the css in css, should it be in a different format? confused.com

Comment: Click on the gear icon next to JS and CSS. You will see "Add External Javascript" in the modal window that appears. In your non-codepen use you'll need to link these scripts `<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: aarrrgggg, I already have them included! and if i add them from external links it stops working, doing my head in!!!! Can you show me example thats working please?

Comment: That codepen is the best example I can show you of it working. Note the CSS is actually LESS and you'll need to click the arrow in the upper right of the CSS panel and select "View Compiled CSS" in order to use it as a CSS file.